# Meteor Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, undefined, referenceerror

In a meteor app I am trying to create a page where if you press one button it shows a template and then if you press another button it hides the same template. I tried to implement this using two buttons with listeners attached which change a boolean (called toggle) to either true or false. The helper method should return the value of true or false to the if statement so anotherTemplate can be displayed but I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined at object.clickDataActionShow
```

It seems that maybe toggle is out of scope? or something entirely different that I can't get my head around.

One thing to mention is that autopublish is removed so is there any chance it could be a publish/subscribe issue?

Either way here is my code:

**list.html**

```
<Template name="list">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info" data-action="show" id="show">Show</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-action="hide" id="hide">Hide</button>
        {{ #if toggleGet }}
            {{> anotherTemplate}}
        {{ /if }}
    </div>
</Template>
```

**list.js**

```
Template.list.created=function(){
    this.toggle = new ReactiveVar(true);
};

Template.list.helpers(
    {
        toggleGet: function(){
            return Template.instance().toggle.get();
        }
    }
);

Template.list.events(
    {
        //Sets toggle to true, shows anotherTemplate
        'click [data-action="show"]': function(event, template) {
            template.toggle.set(true);
        },
        //Sets toggle to false, hides anotherTemplate
        'click [data-action="hide"]': function() {
            template.toggle.set(false);
        }
    }
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

change your created method by onCreated and it should work :)

```
Template.list.onCreated(function() {
  this.toggle = new ReactiveVar(true);
})
```

Comment: I've tried onCreated, onRendered, Meteor startup etc. I don't think that's the issue.